# Maven gives a java version error (ask for java 1.5) even when I have java 1.7 installed

Tags: java, maven

I'm getting an error saying

> (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations) {class path} error:
>    for-each loops are not supported in -source 1.3

when I try to compile a module using maven.

The thing is that the **java version in my machine is 1.7.0_02**

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: It's good that you have java 7 installed but it has nothing to do with the error. Please post your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Are you using Maven 2 or 3?

Answer (score 8):

You may want to include this in your pom.xml file as I had the same problem:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.3.2</version>
              <configuration>
                  <source>1.6</source>
                  <target>1.6</target>
                  <compilerArgument></compilerArgument>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
```

Comment: actually, he should replace all occurrences of 1.6 in this code with 1.7, but still: +1

Comment: I put this in the parent pom but still cannot compile

Comment: Where have you put this in your pom.xml file and could we see the pom.xml file. Also, you may want to change source to 1.7 and target to 1.7 rather than 1.6.

Comment: Yep. I did those changes in the first place. I put this in the parent pom and referred it from the relevant modules.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the value of the JAVA_HOME environment variable. 
For the user acc which is used by maven

Answer (score 0):

The shortest version is to set `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` properties in your pom.xml:

```
<project>
   ....
   <properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.3.2</version>
              <configuration>
                  <source>1.5</source>
                  <target>1.5</target>
                  <compilerArgument></compilerArgument>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
```

by blackpanther

this other too

```
<project>
   ....
   <properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>
```

by rzymek

all together

and clean and build the proyect and that's work fine vatos!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>
<finalName>your project name</finalName>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```